# AdMob linker errors

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, admob

I had developed the app which works fine but using "AdMob" giving me some linker errors...

Using files:-

```
  AdMobDelegateProtocol.h
  AdMobView.h
```

with file :- `libAdMob3.2a`

And the errors are...

```
   Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AdMobView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AdViewController.o
  "_objc_exception_try_enter", referenced from:
      _GSControllerInstance in libGreystripeSDK.a(GreystripeSDK.o)
      _GSExecute in libGreystripeSDK.a(GreystripeSDK.o)
      _GSInitWithCustomServer in libGreystripeSDK.a(GreystripeSDK.o)
      _GSDisplayAd in libGreystripeSDK.a(GreystripeSDK.o)
      _GSSetRelativeRotation in libGreystripeSDK.a(GreystripeSDK.o)
      _GSSetDelegate in libGreystripeSDK.a(GreystripeSDK.o)
      -[GSContentController logSessionEnd] in libGreystripeSDK.a(GSContentController.o)
      ...
  "_objc_exception_extract", referenced from:
      _GSControllerInstance in libGreystripeSDK.a(GreystripeSDK.o)
      _GSExecute in libGreystripeSDK.a(GreystripeSDK.o)
      _GSInitWithCustomServer in libGreystripeSDK.a(GreystripeSDK.o)
      _GSDisplayAd in libGreystripeSDK.a(GreystripeSDK.o)
      _GSSetRelativeRotation in libGreystripeSDK.a(GreystripeSDK.o)
      _GSSetDelegate in libGreystripeSDK.a(GreystripeSDK.o)
      -[GSContentController logSessionEnd] in libGreystripeSDK.a(GSContentController.o)
      ...
  "_objc_exception_match", referenced from:
      _GSControllerInstance in libGreystripeSDK.a(GreystripeSDK.o)
      _GSExecute in libGreystripeSDK.a(GreystripeSDK.o)
      _GSInitWithCustomServer in libGreystripeSDK.a(GreystripeSDK.o)
      _GSDisplayAd in libGreystripeSDK.a(GreystripeSDK.o)
      _GSSetRelativeRotation in libGreystripeSDK.a(GreystripeSDK.o)
      _GSSetDelegate in libGreystripeSDK.a(GreystripeSDK.o)
      -[GSContentController logSessionEnd] in libGreystripeSDK.a(GSContentController.o)
```

Can any one suggest me how can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to add the library to your build options. Have a look at this previous SO question [symbol(s) not found for architecture i386](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4839981/41116)