# Symbols not found for architecture i386?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, viewdidload

basically I've added the EGOTableViewPullRefresh files into my project. The code that I've written should work. However, 2 errors come up when that is triggered by the code in the viewDidLoad.

The Error looks like this: [image]

What seems to be the problem and how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you are importing the correct headers and that the implementation files are linked to your Target.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, I do think I am importing the correct headers. For it to work, I need to add 'QuartzCore.framework' into Link Binary With Libraries. I have done that but does not seem to get rid of the errors. Do you have any other solutions? Thanks.

Comment: Make sure that in your RootViewController` you are importing the correct header. This particular error is generated from your `RootViewController`. If you are importing the correct headers, then you need to make sure that the implementation **(.m)** files are linked to your target.

Comment: Hi WrightsCS, can you please tell me what to do in a more simpler way? I'm quite new to Xcode so am still finding my way around the software. I think I know what you mean but not sure how to do it :/ Thanks.

Comment: Select the EGOTableViewPullRefresh files (all of the .m files) and make are that the Target Membership is selected **(See the first screenshot above.)**

Comment: The last post on this link says to import frameworks from the SimulatorSDK framework? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610709/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386 I am using Xcode 4.3.1 - will it affect me?

Comment: Hey, they are just like your screenshot :/

Comment: Your particular error has to do with `EGOTableViewPullRefresh` itself, not any frameworks.

Comment: The best thing to do for you then would be to look at every aspect of the Demo project and match everything to yours AND read their documentation again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9966/discussion-between-k-honda-and-wrightscs)

Answer (score 2):

let me tell you ,first enter project->`build phases`, now ,you can find the dir of `Compling sources`
,enter into it ,you can't find the EGOREF......m,now add the .m into it ,build and run !