# Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [symbol(s) not found for architecture i386](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839981/symbols-not-found-for-architecture-i386)

I ger this error:

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_AudioServicesPlaySystemSound"
symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

And I import `#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>`.

What can I do about it?

Comment: Have you added the AudioToolbox framework to your project?

Comment: it's an linking error. add framework of audio.

Comment: yes i have added AudioToolbox framework what i can do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to debug the application on a device, simulator don't have iPod or audioplayback. I think....

Answer (score 2):

Importing `<AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>` is necessary, but not sufficient: you need to add a reference to `AudioToolbox.framework` to your project in order for your target to link.

In Xcode, open the project, and choose your main target. On the "Summary" page, find "Linked Frameworks and Libraries", and click [+] at the bottom. Select "AudioToolbox.framework", and click [Add]. This should fix the linking error.

Comment: If you already did this, you should have said so in your question.