# How do I fix these Apple Mach-O Linker Errors?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using Xcode 4.5.  After trying to build an app I've just started on, I got the following Apple Mach-O Linker Error messages.

[image]

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: You haven't included some sources, libraries, or frameworks in your project. For example, `CLLocationManager` is pare of the `CoreLocation.framework`. Go to Target Settings, click on Build Phases, and add that framework to your project.

Comment: `ASIdentifierManager` error indicates that you have not added the `AdSupport.framework` to your project (same problem as the `CoreLocation.framework` issue)

Comment: possible duplicate of [symbol(s) not found for architecture i386](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839981/symbols-not-found-for-architecture-i386)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To fix the first two errors, add the AdSupport and CoreLocation frameworks to your "Link with Binaries" build phase.

The last error is probably caused by you not including all your .m files in the "Compile Sources" build phase - the missing one is likely called GHHaiku.m.

Comment: Yeah, that did it.  I was working from an old version of the Parse framework that didn't require AdSupport and CoreLocation.