# why do frameworks have to be included more than once when nesting libraries in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, static-libraries

I wanted to include a [pdf annotation](http://code.google.com/p/remail-iphone/) demo library (ie cannot look into the source code.. can only use the framework binary) into an [open source email client](http://code.google.com/p/remail-iphone/). Problem was that the email client was non-ARC code whereas the pdf binary library was. The [usual fix](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1490/_index.html) is to simply use the `-ObjC` and `-fobjc-arc` linker flags to go around that.

The problem was that the author of the pdf binary also released some ARC wrapper code around the library that was still important for me to use.. So what i did was that i created an xcode project.. inserted the wrapper code into that and made the wrapper code use the binary library.. then i included the wrapper code as a [static library](http://www.clintharris.net/2009/iphone-app-shared-libraries/).

Then i started getting the [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839981/symbols-not-found-for-architecture-i386): `symbol(s) not found for architecture i386`.. the error was about the wrapper library not being able to find objects defined in the pdf framework binary..

thing is i tested the same code on the iphone then i got `symbol(s) not found for architecture ARM`.. so i knew it wasn't a file architecture problem.. and what was also funny was that if i compiled the wrapper library on its own it worked just fine.

after much hair tearing and wall punching i found out that if i simply include the pdf binary into the parent project (as well as into the wrapper static library).. then things work like a charm.. why is this necessary? i thought the wrapper static library should be stand alone (why can it compile fine on it's own but not be able to find objects in its included framework when compiled as part of a parent project)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the library author pointed out to me that although my solution worked.. i was asking for trouble.. the easiest way to do this is to simply include the ARC files into my project and [individually tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project) them with the -fobjc-arc tag in build phases > compile sources

[image]