# duplicate symbol error in two 3rd libs, with same const definition

Tags: ios, iphone, afnetworking

The two libs are AFNetworking and libcomScore.a.
In AFHttpClient.h, `extern NSString * const AFNetworkingReachabilityDidChangeNotification;`

In AFHttpClient.m, `NSString * const AFNetworkingReachabilityDidChangeNotification = @"***";`

Somehow in some class in the comScore static lib, AFNetworkingReachabilityDidChangeNotification is redefined, causing error

> duplicate symbol _AFNetworkingReachabilityDidChangeNotification in:
>       comScore-iOS-ARMV7_ARMV7S_ARM64-2.1403.14/comScore-iOS-ARMV7_ARMV7S_ARM64-2.1403.14/comScore/libcomScore.a(CSReachabilityManager.o)
>       /Users/apple/lib***.a(AFHTTPClient.o)

I don't want to touch the code in AFNetworking(although I can easily fix it by rename the const.)
So does anybody have any idea ?

Comment: You are right. I think the external library uses `AFNetworking`, try remove the original `AFNetworking` by just unchecking all .m class from settings, and try to import AFNetworking from the library itself. Or, Since you can't change anything in the library, change outside.

Comment: I use lipo to check the inside of libcomScore.a, turns out it isn't using any AFnetworking related file. So I wonder if the lib defines some constant value which just happens to have the same name(AFNetworkingReachabilityDidChangeNotification) in the AFNetworking lib. I rename it to AFNetworkingReachabilityDidChangeNotification111, and the link  error disappears, but changing the AFNetworking code is not what I want.

Comment: @MartaRodriguez I contacted the SDK provider and let them change their code... Turns out they copied some codes from AFNetworking and didn't rename some variables.

Comment: Great! Let see if they publish a new version soon. Thanks @njuxjy!!

Answer (score 1):

Check importation of file you might be importing **.m**  file instead of **.h** file such like

```
#import "myClassName.m"
```

Comment: Adding only Reachability.h to the project (and not Reachability.m) worked and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839981/symbols-not-found-for-architecture-i386

Comment: I don't think it has something to do with the Reachability file, it's just that AFNetworkingReachabilityDidChangeNotification is defined in two libs.  I do have Reachability.h imported by some classes in project, but AFNetworking isn't using Reachability.