# Cordova linker error when Build Active Architecture Only is No "file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)"

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, build, linker-errors

I am using the latest Cordova version in Mac Yosemite, using command line tools did the following

cordova create xxxx com.xxxx xxxx

cd xxxx

cordova platform add ios

now I open the xcode project file under platform and xcode 6 opens up

I then go to Build Setting -> Build Active Architecture Only -> No

Now I run the sample barebone cordova App and it throws a bunch of linker errors

```js
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/joelasirvathamjesudoss/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxx-ehdvqzsskcnwbncktgdnuqbbnloq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libCordova.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /Users/joelasirvathamjesudoss/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxx-ehdvqzsskcnwbncktgdnuqbbnloq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libCordova.a
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CDVLocalNotification", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didReceiveLocalNotification:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_CDVPluginHandleOpenURLNotification", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_CDVRemoteNotification", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_CDVRemoteNotificationError", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVCommandDelegateImpl", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainCommandDelegate in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVCommandQueue", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainCommandQueue in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainViewController in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVCommandDelegateImpl", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainCommandDelegate in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVCommandQueue", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainCommandQueue in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainViewController in MainViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

But when I change Build Setting -> Build Active Architecture Only -> Yes
Everything works fine.

Now I know while submitting to App Store Build Active Architecture Only should be No.

So please advice where I am going wrong

Settings look like the following
[image: Settings for Architectures]
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please confirm your setting looks like this ?

[image]

Comment: can you check all the .m files are added. Check compile sources in the build settings.
This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839981/symbols-not-found-for-architecture-i386#answer-7955906

Comment: I went through that link. I didnt add a single piece of code to the App, its a bare bone Sample PhoneGap build. I didnt add anything to it.These are the only steps I did 1) cordova create xxxx com.xxxx xxxx

2) cd xxxx

3) cordova platform add ios ... and then changed the Build settings

Comment: please check the settings in the Cordova lib too

Comment: Thank you very much, that saved me a whole lot of time in debugging !!

Comment: why you've deleted ?