# Binary upload fails with "Missing 64-bit support"

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store-connect, fastlane

- I'm building Cordova app with

  - `cordova build --device --release`
- uploading it to itunes connect with

  - `pilot upload -i platforms/ios/build/device/AskPal.ipa --verbose`

The publishing process using [Fastlane Pilot](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/pilot) fails with:

> ERROR ITMS-90086: "Missing 64-bit support. iOS apps submitted to the
>   App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK
>   or later. We recommend using the default "Standard Architectures"
>   build setting for "Architectures" in Xcode, to build a single binary
>   with both 32-bit and 64-bit support."

The way I'm "fixing" this is by deleting the ios platform from Cordova, and then reinstalling it with `coordova platform add ios`.

Please tell me there is a way to specify the those build architectures in the Cordova configs.

Answer (score 6):

it is not working

Build Active Architecture

Comment: Where exactly do i specify that?

Comment: Based on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29813445/592641 I found that it's a configuration in xCode. That's not helping me because I've got Cordova project and all those configurations need to be specified inside the Cordova configurations.