# xCode failed linker

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker

When trying to build my iOS app in Xcode, I get the following error message.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "OBJC_CLASS$UIPresentationController", referenced from: _OBJC_CLASS$SSSidebarPresentationController in libtools.a(SSSidebarPresentationController.o) "_OBJC_METACLASS$UIPresentationController", referenced from: _OBJC_METACLASS$_SSSidebarPresentationController in libtools.a(SSSidebarPresentationController.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have the latest version of Xcode.  I have tried cleaning and deleting derived data but that did not help. I've noticed a lot of other people on the internet have similar error messages but the solutions did not help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [symbol(s) not found for architecture i386](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839981/symbols-not-found-for-architecture-i386)

Answer (score 0):

Add the AVFoundation and CoreLocation frameworks to your target. After you do this, delete derived data, clean, and build again.

Also, check in your architectures under build settings and make sure that you have armv7 and armv7s listed under valid architectures. If the above answer does not fix your problem then try adding or removing arm64.